# Change cursor theme with immediate effect

Tags: xorg

Is there a way to change the cursor theme with immediate effect in X, after it starts up?

I've tried `xrdb -merge` which doesn't work (nothing happens).

Answer (score 0):

Well the `xrdb -merge` does set new defaults, but the window manager overrides them with his own settings. These might be read from a config file on wm start. F.e. **kwin** gets these from `~/.kde/share/config/kcminputrc`. Changing that file and doing a `kwin --replace` will apply the new cursor settings to all apps started thereafter.
Find out where your WM stores its cursor settings from the source.